# How to convert a series of data strings into an R matrix

Tags: r, string, matrix

I have a large dataset of strings (nrow = 23468, ncol = 3590) that I want to format into a matrix. However, the columns are currently formatted as strings, so there is only one column.

The file I received has each value in a string separated by a space:

```
row1 "AAGAB 291 0 36" ....
row2 "AAK1 7 0 0" ....
```

I want to format this into a matrix:

```
row1 "AAGAB", "291", "0", "36", ....
row2 "AAK1", "7", "0", "0", ....
```

How can I convert these strings into a matrix in R?

Comment: What have you tried ? Show us some code ...

Comment: reproducible example?

Comment: `df <- read.table(file = "file_having_string_values.txt", sep = " ")`?

Comment: Thanks so much @snoram! read.table worked a treat!